# URL redirection wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I am trying to redirect the URL of my Zend project as follow:

I can access my pages like this:

```
http://senderboard/index.php/en/dashboard
```

but what i want to do is to redirect to have the same page with this this URL:
 `http://senderboard/en/dashboard`

Can i do this redirection or no.

I think there is something to add in my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName senderboard
DocumentRoot /wamp/www/trunk/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory /wamp/www/trunk/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this. In your `VirtualHost` something like this could work.

```
RewriteEngine on        
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Hope it helps you forward.

Comment: Thank you i just forgot to enable mod_rewrite